# Chunked Upload for Django's model field Implementation

Tags: python, django, jquery-file-upload

**The Technical Problem:** realize such a model field that would upload file by chunks.

**Details:**

1. I know about https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and I'm
       going to use it.
2. As I undestand Django's architecture:

   - *SomeModelField* class has *formfield* function, where we can define
     *'form_class'*, that point to *SomeFormField*.
   - Defined *SomeFormField* has attribute *widget*, that could contain *SomeWidget*.
   - *SomeWidget* could have *Media class* that could have *js* variable, which contains tuple of linked scripts.
   - urls.py,pointing to some View function
   - view function

---

Suppose following sources(aren't complete) in accordance with my current understanding:

1. SomeModelField Class

   ```
   class ChunkedFileField(models.FileField):

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(ChunkedFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       description = "Chunked file"

       __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           kwargs['max_length'] = len(UPLOAD_TO) + 1 + FILE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH
           super(ChunkedFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def formfield(self, form_class=None, choices_form_class=None, **kwargs):
           defaults = {'form_class': ChunkedFileFormField}
           defaults.update(kwargs)
           return super(ChunkedFileField, self).formfield(**defaults)
   ```

---

2. SomeFormField Class

   ```
   class ChunkedFileFormField(forms.FileField):

       widget = ChunkedFileUploadWidget

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           print 'ChunkedUploadFileField'
           super(ChunkedFileFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

---

3. SomeWidget Class

   ```
   class ChunkedFileUploadWidget(ClearableFileInput):

       def __init__(self, attrs=None):
           super(ChunkedFileUploadWidget, self).__init__(attrs)
           self.attrs['id'] = 'chunked_upload'

       class Media:
           js = (
               'js/cu.js',
               'js/jquery.js',
               'js/jquery.ui.widget.js',
               'js/jquery.iframe-transport.js',
               'js/jquery.fileupload.js',
               'js/spark-md5.js',
               'js/ksb_django_fields.js',
           )
   ```

---

**Question:**
Am I on right way of constructing chunked uploading for model's field?

I don't understand, how I can solve such situation:
Having form with set of fields, one of which is my ChunkedFileFormField, POST request for form should happen only once, but for my Chunked Field POST request should happen for each chunked part.

How to solve this problem? Any ideas or your realization experience would be brilliant!

P.S.: if it possible with article links, code examples or git sources references.